# Extra Argument For DelegateCommand In WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates, prism, mef

I have implementing `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand` as below to show view based on user Action, But i want to pass an extra argument to `OnExecute` method. I need `FilterInfo` object which can help me filter the data when view get loaded. But i am not sure how can i pass `FilterInfo` object to  `OnExecute`.

```
public class CustomCommand<T> : DelegateCommand<T>,ICommand
{
private string _commandName;
public CustomCommand(string _commandName, Action<T> executeMethod) : base(executeMethod)
        {
            this._commandName = _commandName;
        }
}
```

I have defined base module as below :-

```
public abstract class AbstractModuleBase : IModule
    {
      public List<CustomCommand> _customCommands = new List<CustomCommand>();

      protected void AddCustomCommand<TView>(string name, FilterInfo filterInfo=null)
        where TView : ViewModel
        {
            this._customCommands.Add(new CustomCommand<TView>(name, new Action<TView>(ModuleBase.OnExecute<TView>))
            {
                FilterInfo = filterInfo
            });
        }

        private static void OnExecute<TView>(TView obj)
        where TView : ViewModel
        {
          // Activate UI here.
          // Identified the view bashed on typeof(TView) and get it from MEF or IOC.
          // But here before calling the view i wanted to get FilterInfo obj.
        }
    }
```

And I have defined xaml as below

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CustomCommandList}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate >
               <Button Command="{Binding CustomCommand}"></Button>
</DataTemplate>     
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Above Custom Command is bind with ViewModel.

```
[Export]
    public class DashViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<CustomCommand> _CustomCommandList = AbstractModuleBase._customCommands;
    }
}
```

On Application start up i am calling below method to register view with command:-

```
AbstractModuleBase.AddCustomCommand<DashViewModel>("Dash Name", new FilterInfo("Some Filter"));
AbstractModuleBase.AddCustomCommand<EmpViewModel>("Emp Name", new FilterInfo("Some Filter"));
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? This setup looks a bit strange... why is the custom command list (statically?) in an `IModule`? But your `CustomCommand` can pass its `FilterInfo` to the `executeMethod` when `Execute` is called, of course. You just can't derive from `DelegateCommand`, because its `Execute` isn't virtual.

Comment: I have module and plugin based application using MEF, when module or plugin get loaded that time they need to add there view command in the custom list. This list data is getting render on Dashboard for navigation (binding command). Currently this is working fine, but i want to have custom filter as well. I have very large setup but to explain here,i have added important code flow.

Comment: The custom command list has nothing to do with a module and should be managed separately, I suppose. I'd go so far as to say your custom command list shouldn't contain `ICommand`s but parameters that are passed _to_ an `ICommand`. But if you want to keep it, you'll have to provide your own implementation... probably copying a large chunk of `DelegateCommand`

Comment: can you please point me to example, which can help me to relate your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I suggested in the comment...

Create an `ICommand` implementation that passes something to the parameter, like this sketch:

```
public class FilterCommand : ICommand
{
    public FilterCommand( FilterInfo filterInfo )
    {
        _filterInfo = filterInfo;
    }

    #region ICommand
    public bool CanExecute( object parameter )
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute( object parameter )
    {
        ((Action<FilterInfo>)parameter)( _filterInfo );
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    #endregion

    #region private
    private readonly FilterInfo _filterInfo;
    #endregion
}
```

This way you get a command that you can pass your method (as parameter) *and* a parameter that the command passes on to your method (as constructor argument).